# Microsoft Graph - whether tenant exists

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api

My workflow has logic to create "tenant" on Microsoft (like: `mycompany.onmicrosoft.com`). I want to be sure, that this `mycompany.onmicrosoft.com` is not registered before. Any way to validate it via Microsoft Graph or any other API?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can issue the following request, replacing the tenant name with `mycompany.onmicrosoft.com` *note: the email address doesn't need to actually exist*:

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/userrealm/?user=cj@{{tenant name}}.onmicrosoft.com&api-version=2.1&checkForMicrosoftAccount=false
```

You will get back a payload like this:

```
{
  "NameSpaceType": "Federated",
  "federation_protocol": "WSTrust",
  "Login": "cj@foobar.onmicrosoft.com",
  "AuthURL": "https://msft.sts.microsoft.com/adfs/ls/?username=cj%foobar.onmicrosoft.com&wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn%3afederation%3aMicrosoftOnline&wctx=",
  "DomainName": "foobar.com",
  "FederationBrandName": "FooBar",
  "cloudinstancename": "login.microsoftonline.com"
}
```

`NameSpaceType` will either be:

- `Federated` = Tenant exists and auth is federated,
- `Managed` - Tenant exists and auth is not federated
- `Unknown` - Tenant does not exist

There may be other ways, but this is how I have done it in the past.